# Good library for encoding videos in a dynamic language?

Tags: python, ruby, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm looking for an effective library for encoding videos. I would prefer something in one of the Ruby/Python ilk type languages, but I'd use libraries in C or PHP that were good. Essentially, I'm looking for something that wraps ffmpeg, and would allow me to convert H.264 .mp4's into .theora.ogv, .webm, and (this would be nice) .flv files.

Worst case, I could always just use any language to natively execute ffmpeg, using something like command("ffmpeg -i ...etc."), but I'd prefer something a bit higher level/in-language if possible.

I've already looked at [RVideo](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/), but couldn't get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Python there is [PyMedia](http://pymedia.org/) and [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/).

If you need a raw usage example, see [this](http://www.thefoundation.de/david/2008/sep/11/using-ffmpeg-python/).